# What does the phrase "to cover his feet" refer to in 1 Samuel 24:3?

Tags: translation-philosophy, 1-samuel

1 Samuel 24:3 KJV

> 3 And he came to the sheepcotes by the way, where was a cave;  and Saul went in ***to cover his feet***:  and David and his men remained in the sides of the cave.

Its not clear what this phrase refers to since one translation seems to refer to it as relieving oneself.

1 Samuel 24:3 NASB

> 3 He came to the sheepfolds on the way, where there was a cave; and Saul went in to ***[a]relieve himself***. Now David and his men were sitting in the inner recesses of the cave.

Does this phrase refer to relieving oneself or sleeping?

Comment: Hiph. Impf. 3 ms. יָ֑סֶךְ לָךְ ψ 91:4, וַיָּ֑סֶךְ Ex 40:21 + 2 times; 2 ms. תָּסֵךְ ψ 5:12; Inf. cstr. הָסֵךְ 1 S 24:4; Pt. מֵסִיךְ Je 3:24 (Ges 67 );—screen, cover, 1. specif. c. אֶת־רַגְלָיו, i.e. with long garments, euphemism for evacuating the bowels, from posture assumed, so inf. Ju 3:24, pt. 1 S 24:4 (cf. NH הֵסֵיךְ, and v. GFM, HPS). 

Brown, F., Driver, S. R., & Briggs, C. A. (1977). Enhanced Brown-Driver-Briggs Hebrew and English Lexicon (p. 697). Oxford: Clarendon Press.

Comment: @perrywebb that sounds suspiciously like an answer...

Comment: That IS the answer - place it in the answer box.

Comment: @DrPeterMcGowan I guess where I'm subtle, you are explicit...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the BDB Lexicon the Hebrew translated to "cover his feet" by the KJV (literal translation of לְהָסֵ֣ךְ אֶת־רַגְלָ֑יו) is a euphemism for emptying the bowels:

> Hiph. Impf. 3 ms. יָ֑סֶךְ לָךְ ψ 91:4, וַיָּ֑סֶךְ Ex 40:21 + 2 times; 2 ms. תָּסֵךְ ψ 5:12; Inf. cstr. הָסֵךְ 1 S 24:4; Pt. מֵסִיךְ Je 3:24 (Ges 67 );—screen, cover, 1. specif. c. אֶת־רַגְלָיו, i.e. with long garments, euphemism for evacuating the bowels, from posture assumed, so inf. Ju 3:24, pt. 1 S 24:4 (cf. NH הֵסֵיךְ, and v. GFM, HPS). Brown, F., Driver, S. R., & Briggs, C. A. (1977).

Enhanced Brown-Driver-Briggs Hebrew and English Lexicon (p. 697). Oxford: Clarendon Press.

Answer (score 1):

In other parts where they go somewhere in private?
Saul lay sleeping means he was sleeping.
For they were all asleep means they were all asleep.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

He was sleeping, not relieving himself.
1 Sam.26:7 ....Saul lay sleeping within the trench and his spear stuck in the ground at his bolster... 1 Sam 26:12. ...for they were all asleep....
Ruth 3:7 Was Boaz sleeping or relieving himself. KJV

Comment: Hi Ron, welcome to the site. This answer would benefit from a little more detail. Please be sure to take the site [tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 0):

In Ruth 3:7 he just forgot to take his footwear off. In other parts where they go somewhere in private it's referring to pulling your pants down to the floor in order to do number 1. It's just euphemism. It appears again in Judges 3:24.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Semen made a man unclean.  To avoid this,men masturbated while standing up, requiring him to cover his feet.  So to cover the feet is a euphemism for masturbation.  Masturbation is not a condemned practice or sin in the Bible.  Paul modifies the practice for Christians at 1 Thessalonians 4 3-8. To be practiced with "sanctification and honor" refers to sexual thoughts in line with married couples only.  Of course, you could always have 400 wives like king Solomon. Masturbation was recommended as a tool to prevent fornication.

Masturbation is not a sin in the Bible.  Apparently it was a common practice in early and 1st Century Jewish culture.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

"Cover ones feet" simply means to use ones robe as a blanket in a sense while sleeping in the wilderness. Kind of like  if you were camping with no blanket, you would pull your arms into your shirt to stay warm. The image we have is Saul in a fetal position sleeping with his feet tucked into his garment. Kinda like a baby swaddle.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on both asking and answering questions.